# g++ problem compiling litecoind on Ubuntu Server i386

Tags: litecoin, server, compiling

I am trying to compile litecoind on Ubuntu 11.10 i386 server.

I used this recipe I found:

```
git clone https://github.com/coblee/litecoin.git
cd ~/litecoin/src/
make -f makefile.unix litecoind
mkdir ~/.litecoin/
```

But I am stuck there:

```
make -f makefile.unix litecoind
```

I get:

```
# make -f makefile.unix litecoind
makefile.unix:138: warning: overriding commands for target `obj/nogui/scrypt.o'
makefile.unix:135: warning: ignoring old commands for target `obj/nogui/scrypt.o'
g++ -c -pthread -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wformat -g -DNOPCH  -DUSE_UPNP=0 -DUSE_SSL -fno-stack-protector -fstack-protector-all -Wstack-protector -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -MMD -o obj/nogui/checkpoints.o checkpoints.cpp
checkpoints.cpp:5:59: fatal error: boost/assign/list_of.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [obj/nogui/checkpoints.o] Error 1
```

Anyone know what is going wrong? Seem like a file missing or a problem with the compiler. Also failed on Ubuntu server 11.10 x64...

---

In that case the solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Thank's to David Schwartz for his help.

Comment: Do you have the Boost libraries installed? Did you install whatever package provides "list_of.hpp"? (It may be `boost-devel`. Use your distribution's package management tools to find out.)

Comment: Thank's for your help needed the boost library to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file [~/litecoin/doc/build-unix.txt](https://github.com/coblee/litecoin/blob/master/doc/build-unix.txt) contains build instructions.  The one you're missing is on line 61:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me after typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev libdb++-dev libminiupnpc-dev
```